# How to Calculate column in stored procedure?

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
     C.cid
     , C.custclientid
     , C.client
     , C.company
     , C.product
     , C.producttakendate
     , C.total 
     , P.reciveamt
     , P.dueamt
     , (SELECT TOP 1 rcvdate 
        FROM paymentdata AS PD1 
        WHERE PD1.pclientid = PD.pclientid 
          AND PD1.productname = PD.productname 
        ORDER BY rcvdate DESC) AS rcvdate
     , (SELECT TOP 1 nxtdate 
        FROM paymentdata AS PD1 
        WHERE PD1.pclientid = PD.pclientid 
          AND PD1.productname = PD.productname 
        ORDER BY rcvdate DESC) AS nxtdate
     , (SELECT TOP 1 notepayment 
        FROM paymentdata AS PD1 
        WHERE PD1.pclientid = PD.pclientid 
          AND PD1.productname = PD.productname 
        ORDER BY rcvdate DESC) AS notepayment
FROM
    customermaintenance C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    payment P ON C.custclientid = P.pclientid
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    paymentdata PD ON P.pclientid = PD.pclientid
WHERE
    C.custclientid = 1 AND C.product = 'Software'
```

- c.total have 5000
- p.reciveamt have NULL
- p.dueamt have NULL

I have datalist, which have

```
<asp:Label ID="nextamountLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dueamt") %>' />
```

I want to out put dueamt=5000

then how I calculate in this procedure?

Comment: i try , C.total-p.reciveamt ....... but it get NULL

Comment: You cant do `int - NULL`

Comment: ***Which concrete database system*** is this for? Please add a relevant tag - whether it's `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `mysql`, `sql-server` or whatever else you might be using ...

Comment: Which dbms? (Most dbms products have their own version of stored procedures...)

Answer (score 2):

C.Total - COALESCE(p.reciveamt, 0)

COALESCE returns the first non-null it encounters within its parameters